# Creating a candlestick chart with multiple axes (not twin axis )

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, candlestick-chart, multiple-axes

I have created a candlestick chart that displays the percentage deviation from the moving average, with the percentage as the left side Y-Axis parameter. I want to plot the closing price that corresponds to those percentages( derived by a formula present in my code) on the right side Y-Axis. I am not looking for a twin axis, however. How can I go about doing this?

Currently, I am able to make 2 subplots, with the candlestick on the upper plot and corresponding closing prices on the lower plot. This is my code:

```
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
import pandas as pd
pd.core.common.is_list_like = pd.api.types.is_list_like
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import numpy as np
from mpl_finance import candlestick_ohlc
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter, MonthLocator, YearLocator,  DayLocator
style.use( 'ggplot' )

start_year = int( input( 'Start year: ' ) )
start_month = int( input( 'Start month: ' ) ) #for months before     October, only type in the corresponding digit without the 0
start_day = int( input( 'Start day: ' ) )

print()

end_year = int( input( 'End year: ' ) )
end_month =int( input( 'End month: ' ) ) #for months before October,     only type in the corresponding digit without the 0
end_day = int( input( 'End day: ' ) )

start = dt.datetime( start_year, start_month, start_day )
end = dt.datetime( end_year, end_month, end_day )

print()

ticker = input( 'Ticker: ' ) #should be in Uppercase
ticker = ticker.upper()

df = web.DataReader( ticker, 'morningstar', start, end )

print()

file_name = input( 'What\'s the csv file name that is stored on your device? ( ticker.csv ): ' ) #input should be in Lowercase .csv format
file_name = file_name.lower()

df.to_csv( file_name )

df = pd.read_csv( file_name, parse_dates=True, index_col=0 )


alldays = DayLocator()              # minor ticks on the days
weekFormatter = DateFormatter('%b %d %Y')  # e.g., Jan 12 2018
dayFormatter = DateFormatter('%d')      # e.g., 12

plt.subplot( 2, 1, 1 )
ax = plt.gca()
#fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(alldays)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(weekFormatter)
# ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(dayrmatter)

print()

reply = input( 'How many days\' exponential moving average do you want?: ' )
n = int( reply )

df[ 'EMA' ] = df[ 'Close' ].ewm( span = n, adjust=False ).mean()

df[ 'H' ] = ( df[ 'High' ] - df[ 'EMA' ] ) / df[ 'EMA' ]
df[ 'L' ] = ( df[ 'Low' ] - df[ 'EMA' ] ) / df[ 'EMA' ]
df[ 'C' ] = ( df[ 'Close' ] - df[ 'EMA' ] ) / df[ 'EMA' ]
df[ 'OP' ] = ( df[ 'Open' ] - df[ 'EMA' ] ) / df[ 'EMA' ]

                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           #

df.dropna( inplace=True )

df_corr = pd.DataFrame()

#nbr_days = len( df[ 'Date' ] )

max_h = df[ 'H' ].max()
max_input = int( max_h  * 2.4 * 100 )


min_l = df[ 'L' ].min()
min_input = int( min_l * 2.4 * 100 )

#print( int( min_input ), int( max_input ) )



l = []

for i in range( min_input, max_input ):

value = i / 200

l.append( value )

df_corr['corr'] = l

df_corr.dropna( inplace=True )


df_merged = pd.concat([df.reset_index(), df_corr ], axis=1).set_index("Symbol")

df_merged.to_csv( 'combine2.csv', index=False )

df_ohlc = df_merged

latest_ema = df_ohlc[ 'EMA' ].tail( 1 )
print( latest_ema )

df_ohlc[ 'Price' ] = ( df_ohlc[ 'corr' ] * latest_ema ) + latest_ema  #you need to take the latest EMA

print( df_ohlc )

# plot_day_summary(ax, quotes, ticksize=3)


date_list = df_ohlc[ 'Date' ].map( mdates.datestr2num )


candlestick_ohlc(ax, zip(df_ohlc[ 'Date' ].map( mdates.datestr2num ),
                     df['OP'], df['H' ],
                     df['L'], df['C']),
             width=0.6, colorup= 'g' )

ax.xaxis_date()

##ax2 = ax.twinx()
##s2 = df_ohlc[ 'Price' ]
##ax2.plot( date_list, s2 )

##plt.figure( 2 )
##plt.subplot()
##plt.plot( df_ohlc[ 'corr' ], df_ohlc[ 'Price' ] )

#ax2.plot( df_ohlc[ 'corr' ], df_ohlc[ 'Price' ] )


plt.subplot( 2, 1, 2 )
plt.plot( df_ohlc[ 'corr' ], df_ohlc[ 'Price' ], '.-' )

ax.autoscale_view()
plt.setp(plt.gca().get_xticklabels(), rotation=45,    horizontalalignment='right')


plt.show()
```

This is the output:

```
     Date   Close      High     ...            OP   corr       Price
Symbol                                   ...                                 
SPY    2017-05-30  241.50  241.7900     ...    -0.000663 -0.075 248.783803
SPY    2017-05-31  241.44  241.8800     ...    0.001416 -0.070  250.128581
```

Additionally, this is how the graph looks like:

[image]

Ideally, I want something like this, where the prices on the right y-axis correspond to the percentages on the left, not the dates. (done on Excel):
[image]

Even if plotting multiple axes is not possible, is there a way to link the two plots? For example, if I view 6% as a crucial point on the upper plot and want to check the corresponding price on the lower plot, is there a quicker way than manually checking the corresponding price on the lower plot?

Comment: The scale of the line plot does not appear anywhere on the desired plot. What is that scale? As long as it corresponds to the same dates, you can indeed use a `twinx`, if it doesn't what's the point of showing both graphs in the same plot?

Comment: Thanks. The price does not correspond to the dates. It is calculated as ( percentage * ema + ema ) I am a trader and need to know the price that corresponds to the percentage; that is why I have plotted the line chart below.

Comment: I don't understand this. But possibly someone else will.